# UiPath how to retrieve all column names from Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to retrieve all the column names from an Excel file in UiPath and store all of them in an array, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
(From dc In dt.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)
Select dc.ColumnName).ToArray()
```

See also this [post](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-get-column-names-of-data-table-to-an-array/104386/5).